# Integrals involving Dirichlet kernel and sinc function

Tags: definite-integrals, convolution

I am looking to evaluate the following definite integral involving Dirichlet kernel and sinc function with phase.
\begin{equation}I(d) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin[N(k^{"}-k^{'})]}{\sin(k^{"}-k^{'})} \frac{\sin(c(k^{"}-k^{'}))}{c(k^{"}-k^{'})} \frac{\sin(Nk^{'})}{\sin(k^{'})} \frac{\sin(ck^{'})}{ck^{'}} \exp(ik^{'}d+i\phi(k^{'})) rect \Big(\frac{k^{'}}{k_0}\Big) dk^{'} \end{equation}

Seems to be difficult due to Dirichlet kernel. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, the Dirichlet kernel cancel and with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ instead of $\int_0^{k_0}$ it would have a closed form.

Comment: Kindly explain how they cancel? btw, I corrected for missing constant in the sinc argument.

Comment: With your $c$ they don't anymore. Why would you want to evaluate $\int_0^{k_0}$ ? With $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ it still has a closed form

Comment: $\int_0^{k_0}$ ? --> I have optical low pass filter that limits spatial frequencies.